# which database type are good for arrays?

Tags: php, database, database-design, database-connection

i want my database to support one company haveing many users how can i do that?
 example
users table(UID,username,password)
company table(CID,companyname,usersthatistheownerofthecompany)
 how can i do that? what should i do ? should i make an array in php like 1241,423,4123 *uid's that will be inserted on usersthatistheownerofthecompany row ? or is there any better idea ?

Comment: It is a poor practice to ever store an array in one field in a database. That makes querying the data much harder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want each user to have one *(and never more)* company, you should have :

- `user` table

  - `uid`
  - `username`
  - ...
  - `company_id`
- `company` table

  - `company_id`
  - `company_name`
  - ...

Then, `user.company_id` would be a [**foreign key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), that references `company.company_id`.

And, then, you store :

- One line in `user` for each user

  - Referencing the id of the right company for that user
  - which is the `company_id` of the right line in the `company` table.
- And one line for each company in `company`

There is no user's related information stored in the company table -- and as each user "points" to a company, a company can have several users.

Storing data as an array like you suggested is definitely not quite a good idea -- just not the way a relational database works.

If each user can have several companies, and each comparny can have several users, you'll have to add a third table *(a [**join table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_Table))*, that will indicate, for each user(s), to which company(ies) they are attached to :

- `user` table

  - `uid`
  - `username`
  - ...
- `company` table

  - `company_id`
  - `company_name`
  - ...
- `user_company` table

  - `uid`
  - `company_id`

In this situation, there is no user-related stuff in the `company` table, and there is no company-related stuff in the `user` table : the link between those is in the `user_company` table.

Of course, `user_company.uid` will be a foreign-key to `user.uid` ; and `user_company.company_id` will be a foreign-key to `company.company_id`.

Comment: pascal when do you sleep? hehe, great answers. how about many to many ?

Comment: @Adam : well, right now it's 5:30 pm here, so not the time to sleep ;-) ;;; for the many-to-many part, you'll have to use a join table, like described in the second part of my answer *(which I've edited, so you might not have seen that part before posting your comment)*

Comment: the "cascade" thing can be done by your database server *(depends on the server, though)* ; but I prefer doing that myself in my application's code, and not using that feature of the DB engine ; that way, I know what's being updated/deleted ;;; and cascade doesn't have much to do with many-to-many : many-to-many means that each user can have several companies, and each companies can have several users.

Comment: btw in user_company which one will be PK ? company_id ? uid ? or there are no PK ? and are PK already unique ? or we better put a UQ to a PK ?

Comment: The PK is the identifier of a row ; so, it has to be unique (it is) ;; in user_company, the identifier is the couple user/company ; so, the primary_key will be on those two fields (you can have several fields in an index ; a PK is a specific kind of index)

Answer (score 1):

There is a better idea - it's called a cross-table join. What you do is you create a third table, which contains two columns. In those two columns you store the primary key of the tables you're connecting to eachother.

The idea is that you're creating a relation between a company and a user. In a relational database, relations are indicated between tables by using foreign keys.

Of course, this only applies when you want to connect multiple users to multiple companies (an "M-N" relationship). If you want to connect multiple users to a single company, simply add a column for the company id to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Any relational database is a good way to go. Have a look at [MS SQL](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/) or [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).